# Table disappeared after insert with Ajax BeginForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

After inserting with Ajax BeginForm, I am trying to update my table with UpdateTargetId.The insert operation was successful but my table disappears.I don't understand if I'm missing something or doing something wrong.It may be a simple question for you, but I'm just learning. I'm sorry for that.
Codes I wrote:

Ajax BeginForm :

```
 <div class="modal-body">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Customers", "Customer", new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess="customerSuccess", UpdateTargetId = "customersTable", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customers.musteri_id, new { id = "customer_id" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customers.crud_type, new { id = "crud_type" })

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Müşteri Adı</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customers.musteriAd, new { @class = "form-control customer-inputs", id = "customerNameInput", maxlength = 25, required = "required", pattern = "[A-Za-zğüşıöçĞÜŞİÖÇ\u0020]+" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Müşteri Soyadı</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customers.musteriSoyad, new { @class = "form-control customer-inputs", id = "customerSurnameInput", maxlength = 20, required = "required", pattern = "[A-Za-zğüşıöçĞÜŞİÖÇ\u0020]+" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Telefon Numarası</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customers.musteriTel, new { @class = "form-control customer-inputs", id = "customerPhoneInput", maxLenght = 14, required = "required" })
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Kaydet</button>
                }
            </div>
```

Controller :

```
 public ActionResult Customers()
        {
            try
            {
                CustomerViewModel customerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
                customerViewModel.CustomersList = customerService.GetCustomers();
                return View(customerViewModel);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Sorry, Do you mean when you click `Kaydet` button, The form disappear in the page?